# Best practices for backend support with Android

Tags: android, database, networking, backend

This is a very general open question

What is the best way to provide secure back-end support for an android app? What sort of secure channel? Shared secret? over HTTP/S?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has allot of [issues](http://www.google.com.ar/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=issue+certificate+not+valid+android) with HTTPS (worked out around 2.3, for what i've seen). The best solution, i think, it would be to manually encrypt data all the time. And a couple of crypto libs are 2.x, so depending on what you are targeting it might truelly be "manually". AES?